# Items getting replaced instead of added in HTML Option List box due to page reload when fetching data from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, listbox, html-select

I have this web application written in HTML/CSS, PHP and JavaScript. The code given below simply receives input from a user (serial number/barcode input).

Then the user input is used to search the database if there is an existing item with that serial number/barcode input.

If there is an item in the database with the entered user input (i.e. the entered barcode/serial number), the item name is fetched and added to a HTML list box.

However, my problem is that I can successfully enter my first input, and the item name is returned and added to the HTML option list box. But when I enter a second input, the web page is reloaded and the first input initially entered in the HTML option listbox is gone. So the second input is the only item in the list box.

I expect that every input will be added to the listbox, not replacing the previous input as a result of the page reload.

Please does anyone have an idea of how to avoid this or fix this issue.

The only web development languages I'm familiar with are HTML/CSS, PHP and a little bit of Javascript.

Here is my full code below:

```
<?php
//Connect to Database
include 'init.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mainoperations.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="leftcolumn">   
    <ul>
    <h1>PartsCribber</h1>
    <li><a class="active" href="mainoperations.php">Main Operations</a></li>
    <li><a href="vieweditprofile.php">Profile Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Student Cart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Student Possession</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Update Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="rightcolumn">
    <form method="post" action="mainoperations.php">

        <div class="title">
        <h3>
        <?php echo "Main Operations (1/3)"; ?>
        </h3>
        </div>

        <!-- notification message -->
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
        <div class="error success">
        <h3>
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['success']; 
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
        ?>
        </h3>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

        <div class="input-group">
        <label>Scan Barcode:</label>
        <input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
        <button class="btn" name="insert">Enter</button>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
        <button class="btn" onclick="deleteValue(); return false;">Delete Item</button>
        </div>

        <select id="myselect" size="15" class="select">
        </select>

    </form>

    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) 
{
    $barcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['barcode']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM item_info WHERE serial_no = '$barcode'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $itemname = $row[1];

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            insertValue();

            function insertValue()
            { 
                var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = "<?php echo $itemname; ?>";


                if(option.text.length == 0)
                {   
                    //Do Nothing.
                }
                else
                {
                    option.className = ('option');
                    x.size = "8";
                    x.add(option);
                    document.getElementById("barcode").value = "";
                }
                }

            function deleteValue()
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
                x.size = "8";
                    x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
                }

        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($errors, "Unable to find an item with that Serial Number");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that on every server request (every input) the HTML page is regenerated on the server side and re-rendered on the client side, so yes, all page content is lost. In order to build up a list incrementally you need a (session-)persistent server-side list that collects the data.

Comment: I feel you. Thanks. I'll try storing them in an array and have the array stored in a session.

Comment: Please can you describe what you meant by a (session-)persistent server-side list that collects the data.?

Comment: You should submit the form via ajax and then append the result to the page, this way there are no page reloads so its much more efficient and a nicer experience for the user

Comment: David: By a (session-)persistent server-side list I meant exactly what you proposed, an array (or similar collection) stored in the session. @miknik: Yes, ajax is a possible solution but it will have you end up with all your data just on the client side. Normally, when you have finished selecting your data you might want to have them on the server side, so why not collect them there from the beginning.

Comment: That's not true. You can submit via ajax and add them to the session, the two things aren't mutually exclusive.The ajax request runs exactly the same PHP script upon submission, just without the outdated and clunky whole page refresh.